# How to calculate the expected number of distinct items when drawing pairs?

Tags: combinatorics, probability

Suppose I have a set $\mathcal{S}$ of $N$ distinct items. Now consider the set $\mathcal{P}$ of all possible pairs that I can draw from $S$. Naturally, $|\mathcal{P}| = \binom{N}{2}$. Now when I draw $k$ items (pairs) from $\mathcal{P}$ with a uniform distribution, what is the expected number of distinct items from $S$ in those $k$ pairs?

P.S.: I also asked this question over at [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4453/), but got no answers so far, so I am trying here. Thanks for your time!

**Edit** I pick the pairs without replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For choosing without replacement, here is an exact answer.  Assuming $n \geq 2$, so that there is at least one pair, and $1 \leq k \leq \binom{n}{2}$, so that you're choosing at least one pair but not more than the total number of pairs, the expected value is

$$n - \left(\frac{n^2 - 3n - 2k + 4}{n-1}\right) \frac{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{k-1}}{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{k-1}}.$$

We can assume that we are choosing pairs in order.  Let $X_k$ be the number of distinct items from $S$ through $k$ pairs.  Let $Y_i$ be the number of items in the $i$th pair that did not appear in any of the previous pairs.  So $X_k = \sum_{i=1}^k Y_i$.

Now, $Y_i$ is either 0, 1, or 2.  Since there are $\binom{n}{2} - n + 1$ pairs that do not contain a given item and $\binom{n}{2} - 2n + 3$ pairs that do not contain either of two given items, we have
$$P(Y_i = 1) = \frac{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{i-1} + \binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{i-1} - 2 \binom{\binom{n}{2} - 2n + 3}{i-1}}{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{i-1}}$$
and
$$P(Y_i = 2) = \frac{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 2n + 3}{i-1}}{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{i-1}}.$$
Thus 
$$E[Y_i] = 2\frac{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{i-1}}{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{i-1}}.$$

It can be proved by induction that 
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{\binom{M}{i}}{\binom{N}{i}} = \frac{(N+1)\binom{N}{k} - (M-k)\binom{M}{k}}{(N+1-M)\binom{N}{k}}.$$

Thus 
$$E[X_k] = \sum_{i=1}^k E[Y_i] = 2\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{i-1}}{\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{i-1}} $$ 
$$= 2\frac{(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-1+1)\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k-1} - (\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - n + 1 - k + 1)\binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{k-1}}{(\binom{n}{2} - 1+1-\binom{n}{2} + n - 1)\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{k-1}}$$
$$= \frac{n(n-1)\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k-1} - (n^2 - 3n - 2k + 4)\binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{k-1}}{(n - 1)\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{k-1}}$$
$$= n -\frac{(n^2 - 3n - 2k + 4)\binom{\binom{n}{2} - n + 1}{k-1}}{(n - 1)\binom{\binom{n}{2} - 1}{k-1}}.$$

Comment: @ Mike: Cool. I think your answer is correct!

Comment: +1 for the Latex labor alone. I questioned this answer at first because when I plugged in small values of $n$ and $k$, the formula wanted to divide by zero. For $k = 0$, and then for $(n,k) = (1,1)$ and even $(n,k) = (2,2)$. But it settled down and started producing answers that match a monte carlo simulation. Nicely done.

Comment: @I. J. Kennedy: Thanks for verifying the formula!  I was a little concerned that I had missed something somewhere.  As far as the small values, I assumed $n \geq 2$ (as otherwise you can't construct pairs), $k \geq 1$ (so that you're drawing at least one of the pairs), and $k \leq \binom{n}{2}$ (since you can't draw more pairs than there are).  (The last case rules out the $n = 2$, $k = 2$ scenario.)  Without those assumptions, you're right; the formula can yield a division by zero.

Answer (score 3):

You are picking edges from a complete graph and looking for the expected number of vertices that get picked.

Consider the expected number of vertices that *don't* get picked.

The probability that a vertex gets picked in 1 try is $\dfrac{2}{n}$.

Thus it does not get picked in all tries is $(1-\dfrac{2}{n})^k$.

Thus the expected number of vertices that don't get picked is $n(1-\dfrac{2}{n})^k$

and thus the expected number of vertices that get picked is

$n(1 - (1-\dfrac{2}{n})^k)$

As Ross points out, this assumes you pick the pairs with replacement.

Comment: I think so. I made a mistake in the comment. It must be that $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i = 1$ if vertex $i$ was picked at some try, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: This is fine if the edges are picked with replacement.  Otherwise, vertices that have not been picked are more likely to be picked on subsequent draws.

Comment: @Ross: You are right. I was assuming with replacement.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very helpful answer. Just the idea of picking edges from a complete graph helps me understand the problem better! On the other point, I do indeed pick without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the exact probability of drawing $t$ unique vertices using inclusion-exclusion. We can estimate this probability as

$\binom{n}{t} \binom{\binom{t}{2}}{k}$

but you're overcounting instances when less than $ t $ vertices actually appear; you can fix that using inclusion exclusion.

Given that, you can try to calculate the expectation directly.

---

You can also try to work your way from Moron's formula. His formula gives the expectation when *k* edges are drawn with replacement. We know that distribution of the number of distinct edges drawn, so we can express the expectation when *k* edges are drawn with replacement using the expectations when $k_0$ unique edges are drawn for $k_0 \leq k$. We get linear equations and maybe we can solve them to find the probability when *k* unique edges are drawn.