# Expected number of distinct values selected from binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The first part of the question ([Finding expected number of distinct values selected from a set of integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/finding-expected-number-of-distinct-values-selected-from-a-set-of-integers)) has been answered a few times.

Can someone provide a solution if we're drawing from a binomial distribution instead of a uniform distribution?

In other words, let X1,X2,X3,…,Xk be independent Binomial (n,p) random variables. What is the expected number of distinct values in the set {X1,…,Xk}?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "drawing from a binomial distribution"? Drawing is something that takes place on base of a distribution. If it happens on base of uniform distribution then all objects have equal chances to be drawn. What are the objects here?

Comment: Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots, X_k$ are independent Binomial $(n,p)$ random variables. Do you ask about the number of distinct values in the set $\{X_1,\ldots,X_k\}$?

Comment: @NCh yes that's exactly what I mean! Thanks for the elegant formulation, I've updated the definition.

Comment: This is the "coupon collector's problem" with unequal probabilities.  See the remarks on the general case at the bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem and the citation to a paper of Flajolet, although it may not be that easy to extract an answer from the formula there.

Comment: I have a feeling (from empirical evidence) that the number of distinct values in the set {X1,…,Xk} follows a geometric distribution but cannot demonstrate it mathematically. Anyone able to help?