# Understanding distribution using Stirling number of the second kind

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

I have adapted this question from this question, I don't fully understand the answers given there/
[Understanding distribution using Stirling number of the second kind inclusion exclusion approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753782/understanding-distribution-using-stirling-number-of-the-second-kind-inclusion-ex)

**Problem**
I want to distribute $n=3$ distinguishable items to $r=3$ distinguishable groups such that

- repetition of items is not allowed
- each group contains one or more items.

**Solution**

We follow inclusion-exclusion principle which, in turn, takes form of Stirling number of second kind.

- $3^3=27$ ways to distribute $3$ items to $3$ groups such that $3$ groups can contain zero or more items.
- (Subtract) $2^3\times\binom{3}{1}=24$ ways to distribute $3$ items to $2$ groups such that $2$ groups can contain zero or more items (i.e., $1$ group is guaranteed to be empty).
- (Add) $1^3\times \binom{3}{2}=3$ ways to distribute $3$ items to $1$ group such that $1$ group can contain zero or more items (i.e., $2$ groups are guaranteed to be empty).

Final answer $=27-24+3=6$. These six distributions corresponds to following distributions:

```
| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
-------------------------------
| 1       | 2       | 3       |
| 1       | 3       | 2       |
| 2       | 1       | 3       |
| 2       | 3       | 1       |
| 3       | 1       | 2       |
| 3       | 2       | 1       |
```

**Q1.**

Does the table below correctly list all 27 possibilities?

```
|    | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
|----|---------|---------|---------|
| 1  | 123     |         |         | 123 in one group
| 2  |         | 123     |         |
| 3  |         |         | 123     |
------------------------------------
| 4  | 12      | 3       |         | 12 in one group
| 5  | 12      |         | 3       |
| 6  | 3       | 12      |         |
| 7  |         | 12      | 3       |
| 8  |         | 3       | 12      |
| 9  | 3       |         | 12      |
------------------------------------
| 10 | 23      | 1       |         | 23 in one group
| 11 | 23      |         | 1       |
| 12 | 1       | 23      |         |
| 13 |         | 23      | 1       |
| 14 |         | 1       | 23      |
| 15 | 1       |         | 23      |
------------------------------------
| 16 | 13      | 2       |         | 13 in one group
| 17 | 13      |         | 2       |
| 18 | 2       | 13      |         |
| 19 |         | 13      | 2       |
| 20 |         | 2       | 13      |
| 21 | 2       |         | 13      |
------------------------------------
| 22 | 1       | 2       | 3       | All digits/items in different groups
| 23 | 1       | 3       | 2       |
| 24 | 2       | 1       | 3       |
| 25 | 2       | 3       | 1       |
| 26 | 3       | 1       | 2       |
| 27 | 3       | 2       | 1       |
```

**Q2.**

How so these lines to the (24 &3) correspond to?

- Does the 3 correspond to the first three lines?
- Does the 24 correspond to lines 4 to 27?

**Q3.** Where does that $24$ come from?

- The first part is because there are 3 ways to exclude one bin = 3
- I am struggling to understand the groups of eight though can someone please explain how they are formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Looks OK to me.

Q2: The 24 corresponds to lines 1..21, *with lines 1..3 counted twice* because each of those can occur two ways, depending on which group we "guarantee to be empty". The 3 corresponds to lines 1..3.

Q3: We can pick one bin to *guarantee* the emptiness of, in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways. Then we can pick how to allocate the 3 objects to the 2 remaining bins in $2^3$ ways. The thing that I think you're finding strange is that *this counts some possibilities twice*, namely those where more than one bin is empty.

This sort of "overcounting" is always there in inclusion-exclusion situations. You overcount, then you correct, then you find you overcorrected so you correct for that, etc., and the inclusion-exclusion principle is a way of doing the bookkeeping to make sure that you end up counting everything exactly once.