# Expected Number of Distinct Numbers in N trials from a set.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given the set of numbers from 1 to n: { 1, 2, 3 .. n } We draw n numbers randomly (with uniform distribution) from this set (with replacement). What is the expected number of distinct values that we would draw?

I came across this question on [Brainstellar](https://brainstellar.com/puzzles/probability/208). I have understood a way to solve this problem using [Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/finding-expected-number-of-distinct-values-selected-from-a-set-of-integers#) but I am not able to understand the fault in my methods.

$X_i$ represents if I have picked up a unique number on the $i^{th}$ pick. Naturally,
$X_i$

```
  = 1 when I have picked up a number that was not picked earlier.
  = 0 when I have picked up a number that was already picked earlier.
```

$E[\sum_{i=0}^n X_i]$ should be my answer to the problem.
$E[X_1] = 1$ as I would definitely pick a unique number on the first trial.

$E[X_i] = \frac{(n-1)^{i-1}}{n^{i-1}}$  where $i \neq 1$

The first part is the probability that in the $i-1$ trials a particular number was never picked. This is how I got the $E[X_i]$.

Now all i need to do is $1 + \sum_{i=2}^n E[X_i]$

And what I get is $$1 + \frac{(n-1)}{n} + \left(\frac{(n-1)}{n}\right)^n$$

I am not able to find the folly in this approach.

PS: I am not a maths student so kindly forgive any silly mistakes you might find. I have been struggling for hours trying to find the mistake but to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand your computation of $E[X_i]$. What is that $\frac 1n$ doing? Suppose $n=2$.  Then the correct answer is $E[X_2]=\frac 12$, yes?  But your formula gives $E[X_2]=\frac {1^1}{2^1}\times \frac 12=\frac 14$.

Comment: Also, if you compute $1+\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]$ aren't you adding $E[X_1]$ twice?

Comment: @lulu I have made the changes. Please help me out now!

Comment: But with those corrections, the answer is indeed $\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]$.  I don't think you evaluated that sum correctly, however.

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/expected-number-of-unique-items-when-drawing-with-replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have figured it out.

Mistake made:
I tried adding $1$ even after summing over from $i$ = 1 to $i = n$

Also the E[$X_i$] was calculated wrong the first time as $\frac{1}{n}$$\left(\frac{(n-1)}{n}\right) ^ {i-1}$

Correct value is
E[$X_i$] = $\left(\frac{(n-1)}{n}\right) ^ {i-1}$

So the answer is $\sum_{i=1} ^n \left(\frac{(n-1)}{n}\right) ^ {i-1}$

The answer is $n$$\left(1 - \left(\frac{(n-1)}{n}\right) ^ {n}\right) $ 
Thanks to @lulu in the comments for pointing out

Comment: An the inner parenthesis goes to $\frac 1e$ as $n$ gets large, so you get a fraction $1-\frac 1e$ of the numbers.